# Doctrine create foreign key

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble with foreign keys in doctrine. I have a "User"-table and a "Orders"-table. Now I want to have a foreign key from userID in the orders-table to the id in the user-table. The orders-entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Application\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *  name="Orders",
 *  options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci",
 *   "charset"="utf8",
 *   "engine"="InnoDB"
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\TestBundle\Entity\OrdersRepository")
 */
class Orders
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(
     *  name="id",
     *  unique=true,
     *  type="integer",
     *  options={"unsigned"=true}
     * )
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(
     *  name="userID",
     *  type="integer",
     *  nullable=false,
     *  options={"unsigned"=true}
     * )
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userID;

    // ...
}
```

The user-entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Application\TestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *  name="User",
 *  options={"collate"="utf8_general_ci",
 *   "charset"="utf8",
 *   "engine"="InnoDB"
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\TestBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(
     *  name="id",
     *  unique=true,
     *  type="integer",
     *  options={"unsigned"=true}
     * )
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately **no foreign key will be set**. It is not in the SQL-query. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you persist your entity? Can you paste the *relevant* part from your controller action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple. It can only be a relation or a datatype (string, object, int). So my example requires a relation, so I had to remove the `@ORM\Column`-annotation and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if your database table engine type does not support foreign keys (such as MyISAM). Try changing your engine type for example to InnoDB, then run

```
console doctrine:schema:update
```